# Virtual host not working

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, ubuntu-11.04

I have the virtual host setup in my /etc/apache2/sites-available and the file name is roomstaysback.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
DocumentRoot "/var/www/roomstaysback/public"    
ServerName roomstaysback

#This should be omitted in the production environment
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

<Directory "/var/www/roomstaysback/public">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts file contain the following:

```
127.0.0.1   roomstaysback

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

The sites-enabled also contain the roomstaysback and it enabled properly. My code is in /var/www/roomstaysback/public and it also contain the .htaccess file with proper mod rewrite rule.

But when I trying to open roomstaysback in browser it shows nothing (blank page).

Is my virtual host is configured properly or not. If it then where should be the problem. If not then help for configuring it properly. Thanks.....

Comment: If a blank page is appearing; to me it seems that virtual host is configured properly. However, there is an error in the code/page that is begin loaded. You can turn on php errors or view error log to see what is wrong!

Comment: Have you tried placing an html file in the folder and loading it (that is, making a request that doesn't involve PHP)? If that loads correctly, you need to check the PHP logs.

Comment: thanks Ozair...I added the line error_reporting(E_ALL); in my application.ini but still facing same problem

Comment: yes DCoder....I placed html file into the folder and load it and it running properly...no problem in it.

Comment: @kaj: then your problem is somewhere else, not in VirtualHost config.

Comment: and what do you get if you remove .htaccess?

Comment: what's your display_errors setting?

Comment: @dezso:error_reporting('e_all');

Comment: @kaj: yes, you wrote that - but what's your `display_errors` setting?  Try `ini_set("display_errors", "On")`

Comment: @dezso: same problem...but my index.php is calling when I echo it showing the message. I think following code is not working : `$application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');

$application->bootstrap();
$application->run();`

Comment: @kaj: probably a problem in `APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'`?  or with `APPLICATION_ENV`

Comment: @deszo: Actully the `$application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');` returning blank value thats why the bootstrap not calling.

Comment: you should ask that separately

Comment: @deszo: Finally solve it...Actually some code in application.ini is in PHP 5.3 and I configured my site in PHP 5.2 so after debugging it I solved the problem. Also /var/www/roomstaysback folder was in read only mode then I changed permission of it solved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your /var/www/roomstaysback folders permission if it is read only mode then change it to the read-write mode.

Answer (score 1):

i had faced the same problem while setting up virtual host in ubuntu for zend framework.add a trailing slash in the following.

```
<Directory /var/www/roomstaysback/public/>
```

here is the tutorial that might help you.

http://blog.code4hire.com/2011/03/setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-apache-on-ubuntu-for-local-development/